# Default font list in the dropdown of CKEditor

Tags: css, fonts, ckeditor, editor, ckeditor4.x

Wanted to know from where does CKEditor4 fetches the default fonts shown in the drop-down. Is it the fonts supported by the OS on which it is opened? Or does it have some hard coded values.

Could not find related to this in the official documentation.

[Drop-down font list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sudwo.png)

Comment: Apparently it's a predefined list of  so called "web-safe" fonts (Most likely available on every Windows and Apple OS). I tested the editor in a virtual machine Linux Mint: The list was unchange - including fonts not by default available on Linux distros.